# Git merge master does not pull in file from that branch

Tags: git

So I have two branches, my primary `master` branch and a new development branch. Inside the `master` branch a new file has been added to the repository. I noticed this file was not in my development branch, thus giving me an error.

When I do `git merge master` from the development branch it says: `Already up to date.`

If I checkout `master` I notice the file is indeed there, so the branch must be up-to-date, however, it is not in my development branch.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: And you didn't delete this file in your branch?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen no, it's both in my local and remote git

Comment: You say you have a *new* development branch. What I means was that after creating this development branch, you didn't delete this particular file on your development branch?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen No. As I told you: the file is in my master branch. If I do "git pull" on master, it is up-to-date. If I go into github repository and "Find File.." I clearly see the file. Also the file is not in gitignore.

Comment: @FooBar Can you share the github repo url?

Comment: I understand it is in your master branch, what I am asking is that you ensure you didn't delete it on your development branch. In other words, I want to make sure you didn't do the following: 1) Create a new development branch, 2) Delete the file (on your development branch), 3) Try to merge with master to restore the file.

Comment: Thanks @LasseVågsætherKarlsen; for some reason I think that's what happend. I tried making a new branch from master, then merge my development branch into that branch, and I noticed that the file was being deleted on merge. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has become evident from the comment thread on your question, you apparently deleted the file on your development branch.

Since this is a *change* as far as git is concerned, it is relevant when considering merges.

Since you say that creating yet another new branch and merging your development branch into it deletes the file, then that is a change that occurred on that development branch.

If the same file had been changed on master, before you tried to merge master into your development branch, you would've noticed a merge conflict because a file that was deleted (on your branch) was changed (on the branch you merge from.)

In your case, since the file is now deleted, and it wasn't changed on master, merging master into your development branch will not bring back that file.

You have various options available to you:

1. Revert the commit (completely or partially) that deleted the file
2. Create a new development branch from master (with the file) and lift over the changes you want to keep from your old development branch
3. Restore the file by checking it out from a previous commit (actually, this will be similar to option 1 in terms of results)